# /usr/bin/gem:8:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I install and uninstall ruby 1.8 and 1.9, and install again, and now i am lost...

The 'gem' doesn't work...
This is the only message i get:

> /usr/bin/gem:8:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
>     from /usr/bin/gem:8

gem -v - give back the same result

---

Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

which ruby:
/usr/bin/ruby

which gem
/usr/bin/gem

ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [x86_64-linux]

apt-get install rubygems
rubygems is already the newest version.

rails -v
getopt: invalid option -- 'v'
Terminating...

Comment: What do you get when you do this: gem list --local

Comment: The same thing : /usr/bin/gem:8:in `require': no such file ...

Comment: have you tried running gem update --system?

Comment: The same thing : /usr/bin/gem:8 ... something is not good with the command itself, but i can't find how to reinstall it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use apt-get to uninstall, then reinstall ruby. You say you have installed two different versions of ruby (1.8.x, and 1.9.x), so both will have to go.

```
sudo apt-get uninstall ruby1.8
sudo apt-get uninstall ruby
sudo apt-get purge ruby1.8
sudo apt-get purge ruby
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Do not worry if the purge and autoremove commands tell you nothing was done.

Now do:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

This will get you ruby version 1.9.3 --that's the latest on my box using apt-get. Once that is done, then do:

```
gem list --local
```

and you should get a short list.

To get rails do:

```
sudo apt-get install rails
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. now i get /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:9:in `require': no such file to load -- thread (LoadError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:9
 from /usr/bin/gem:8:in `require'
 from /usr/bin/gem:8

Comment: apt-get uninstall ruby1.8 - E: Invalid operation uninstall
apt-get uninstall ruby - E: Invalid operation uninstall

Comment: I use root user. In my case it is something  with the installation that go's wrong, it doesn't install the ruby properly.